# Custom csv file name using to_csv Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm working on writing a pandas DataFrame to a CSV file using to_csv :

`df.to_csv("Output.csv")`

I'm looking to customize the naming of the csv file by adding the actual datetime so it should look like this : `Output_2021-12-17T14:09:09Z`

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `f-string`s with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html):

```
print (f"Output_{pd.to_datetime('now').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}.csv")
Output_2021-12-17T13:12:58Z.csv

df.to_csv(f"Output_{pd.to_datetime('now').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}.csv")
```

Comment: Hum, got this error message when trying to run this : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Output_2021-12-17T13:27:11Z.csv' Is it smthg wrong with my OS ?

Comment: @Amamra - I think yes, need remove `:` like `df.to_csv(f"Output_{pd.to_datetime('now').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ')}.csv")`